# Python - Parsing large text file and inserting data into database

Tags: python, django, io

I may be undertaking too large of a project for a noob, but I'm trying to host an unofficial API for KickassTorrents. Currently, they offer text dumps of their entire database that are usually around 650Mb.

Right now I'm reading the text file with Python and inserting it into my database using Django's ORM:

```
with open('hourlydump.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            sections = line.split('|')

            Torrent.objects.create(...)
```

Using their hourly dump as a test (which is ~900kb), I came up with an execution time of about two minutes. Obviously scaling up to 700Mb with that speed is impractical.

I'm thinking that this problem has a solution, but I'm just not sure what it would be. I'm sure that the time to load their entire database into my own will still be significant, but I'm hoping there's a more efficient solution that I don't know about that will reduce the execution time to something less than 25 hours.

EDIT: The bottleneck is almost definitely inserting into the database.

Inserting with the ORM:

```
 $ python manage.py create_data
   Execution time: 134.284000158
```

Just creating the objects and storing them in a list:

```
$ python manage.py create_data
Execution time: 1.18499994278
```

I appreciate any guidance you might have.

Comment: what does the input file look like?

Comment: Like this (with each record on a new line):

torrent_info_hash|torrent_name|torrent_category|torrent_info_url|torrent_download_url|size|category_id|files_count|seeders|leechers|upload_date

Comment: that's one line?  and each chunk between `|` goes into one column in a table?

Comment: That's the format of each line. I'm tokenizing each section (torrent_info_hash, torrent_name, etc.) and inserting them into their appropriate fields in a Torrent object and then creating that row in the db. I guess the overhead could be in creating thousands of objects, I'm not sure.

Comment: for stuff like this I often find it much faster to use the `csv` module to read the data and then load into db using the `sqlite3` module directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp, I'm dumb.

Bulk create is my new friend.

If anyone has the same problem, don't insert rows one at a time. Each create() call is one insert statement. Instead, add the objects to a list, and then bulk_create(the_list).

Answer (score 1):

Try this using [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

```
from itertools import islice
with open('hourlydump.txt', 'r') as f
    my_lines = islice(f, N) #number of lines taken in each iteration.
    #Do your operations here
```

`my_lines` is a generator object, that gives you each line of the file and can be used in a loop like this:

```
for line in mylines:
    print line
```